# fire the 'itemtap' event dynamically to a list item

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

When using Sencha Touch 2, I want to fire the `itemtap` event dynamically to an item of a list (`Ext.List`), I did it in this way:

```
Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).container.fireEvent('itemtap', null, null, ITEM_INDEX,
    new Event('itemtap'));
```

Running this line, the `itemtap` event was fired on the `ITEM_INDEX` of the `LIST_ID`. Now when updating my framework to sencha touch 2.1 this way is not working anymore...

Is their another way to fire this event dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I use this syntax : fireEvent('itemtap', index, node). To get the node object, you should use [getNode()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.DataView-method-getNode) or [getAt()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-getAt).

```
// For example, to tap the first item
// sencha 1.1
Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).fireEvent('itemtap', 0, Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).getNode(0)); 
// sencha 2.1
Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).fireEvent('itemtap', 0, Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).getAt(0));
```

Regards

Comment: `Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).getNode(0)` - no such method `getNode`

Comment: `Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).fireEvent('itemtap', 0, Ext.getCmp(LIST_ID).getAt(0));` Will do the magic.

Comment: The method has been renamed from sencha 1 => sencha 2. I added links to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

a working example is

```
listobj.fireEvent('itemtap',listobj,indexofListInt);
```

In general if you have an event (in st api documentation) defined as:
itemtap( this, index, target, record, e, eOpts )

to fire an event you must:

```
obj.fireEvent('eventname',this, index, target, record, e, eOpts )
```

the args after 'eventname' are in the exact right order as in the api doc for the event signature!

that's all folks!